# How to add padding and increase width of Navigation Drawer icon in Action bar?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to increase width of Navigation drawer icon and add left and right padding to it. Any idea how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For padding you can use:

```
ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(android.R.id.home);
view.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Regarding the Icon width have you tried using a larger icon?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the styles:

```
 <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">#FE1B56</item>
    <item name="barSize">20dp</item>
    <!--<item name="thickness">3dp</item>-->
</style>
```

Add this in your parent theme

```
 <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted the icon to be wider, so I used Gimp (image editor) to make it wider (just added a few more pixels of the grey lines and extra transparency to the right). The Action Bar displays the icon appropriately and moves the other elements over to fit (like the action bar title). I've provided the image below in case you want to use it:
[image: ic_drawer.png wider]

Comment: I tried the same but its too cluttered this way, need spacing.

Comment: If you add transparency to the left side of the image it will appear padded (I believe that's what you want, right?).

Comment: Tried it. But the width of button is constant and thus the magnitude of padding I want can't be achieved by doing so.